# I pull the branch with tag in the groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to pull specified branch with tag.

So i write job as following

```
job('abc'){
    scm{
        git('ssh://git@abc.git', 'refs/tags/test-tag1')
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

I inputted branch Name or commit into 2nd param, it will pull the specified branch.

It can work with tag from the document of [Jenkins Job DSL Plugin].

I want to know why it doesn't work, Or my job is wrong.

Comment: my job has checkout the latest branch from git every times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the tag name. This works for me:

```
job('example'){
  scm {
    git('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git', 'job-dsl-1.53')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

```
sum
```

needs to be

```
scm
```

:)