# Jenkinsfile in groovy read the git tag

Tags: jenkins, groovy, git-tag

I would like to prepare 2 jobs in the same jenkins server that will read from a specific branch. I have to use the git tag for one of the jobs as to separate them somehow.

Please, could you paste some code containing the job trigger in jenkins using a git tag ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195900/jenkins-git-plugin-how-to-build-specific-tag

Comment: Thanks @CommodoreBeard thing is that jenkins changed lately and some of the old UI functions need to be placed into a groovy pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on your comment:

> jenkins changed lately and some of the old UI functions need to be placed into a groovy pipeline

I think this is a duplicate of this question: [I pull the branch with tag in the groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651385/i-pull-the-branch-with-tag-in-the-groovy)

The answer is perfect for what you are asking.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @commodorebeard it helps. I will figure out how to get the tag from another job (in a different jenkins environment) that created the initial tag